# Split DataFrame into 2 lists by different column values

Tags: r

**I have an example DataFrame (df).**

```
df <- data.frame(Class = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                 Numbers = c(4,2,4,1,4),
                 Names = c("Alice", "Daniel", "Helen", "John", "Alex"),
                 Weight = c(60, 72, 90, 100, 70)
                 
)
```

**What I want is to create two lists with 5 DataFrames in each, with such conditions.**

**1)** The first list (list_1) should contain DataFrames split by df$Class,
so every DataFrame will contain rows only for corresponding column values.
and this is **easily done by**

```
list_1 <- split(df,df$Class)
```

As a result I get a list of 5 distinct DataFrames for each class:
[image]

**2)**  ***This is where I struggle*** While the second list (list_2) should also contain DataFrames split by df$Class, but in a such way that first DataFrame in the list_2 will contain all row values except for the values of the first DataFrame in the list_1 and so on.

**So, my desired output should look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `names` of the first `list` and then `subset` the 'Class' that is not equal (`!=`) to the looped value

```
list_2 <- lapply(names(list_1), function(cls) subset(df, Class != cls))
```

-output

[image]